# Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible in Java to access private field str via reflection?
For example to get value of this field.

```
class Test
{
   private String str;
   public void setStr(String value)
   {
      str = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: The question would have been greatly improved if it included "I tried this..." with the code in question.

Comment: The question is a dupe - it has been asked and answered a few times

Answer (score 198):

Yes, it absolutely is - assuming you've got the appropriate security permissions. Use `Field.setAccessible(true)` first if you're accessing it from a different class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Other
{
    private String str;
    public void setStr(String value)
    {
        str = value;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        // Just for the ease of a throwaway test. Don't
        // do this normally!
        throws Exception
    {
        Other t = new Other();
        t.setStr("hi");
        Field field = Other.class.getDeclaredField("str");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(t);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

And no, you shouldn't normally do this... it's subverting the intentions of the original author of the class. For example, there may well be validation applied in any situation where the field can *normally* be set, or other fields may be changed at the same time. You're effectively violating the intended level of encapsulation.

Comment: There are very few instances where you should do this, as Jon noted.  I have unfortunately had to do it more than I care to admit, and it makes for VERY ugly code.

Comment: FAIL. If you remove the call to `setAccessible` it still works, even with a  security manager present. :) But +1 for "you shouldn't normally do this".

Comment: @Tom: Thanks, fixed up the example to a situation where you *do* need to do it :)

Comment: Nice correction. (See Guideline 6-4 of Secure Coding Guidelines Version 2.0 for the Java Programming Language: http://java.sun.com/security/seccodeguide.html )

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain why?

Comment: @JoseMartinez: If you don't know the name of the variable, I don't see how *this* question is relevant. Perhaps you ought to ask a new question which explains what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it is relevant.... the question is accessing private fields using reflections.  In your answer the user must have the name of the variable.  Another variation is where the user does not have the name of the variable.  But I did find the answer... just call the getDeclaredFields() method without any arguments to get the Field[].  Thanks!

Comment: @JoseMartinez: Well in the OP's question, they're clearly aware of the name. If you don't know what variable you're trying to access, you can get *all* of them, but you'd still need to work out which one you were interested in...

Comment: This answer would provide more value, if you could elaborate **why** *"you shouldn't normally do this..."*

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes: See if my edit (just an elaboration at the bottom) helps.

Comment: `a.setAccessible(true); String var = a.getName(); a.get(var)` gives me `Can not set final to java.lang.String`

Comment: @Ava: Interesting - it still works for me. Depends on the JVM, I suspect. Or maybe I'm mosunderstanding your example...

Comment: @JonSkeet why java allow this to access private members? why java created `setAccessible()` method?

Comment: @JonSkeet this method doesn't seem to work when I do It multiple times (3 being the number). I have some more info on it here: bukkit.org/threads/how-to-get-private-field-java-8.422602/#post-3392416

Comment: @RookieTEC9: You should post a new question on Stack Overflow, with a short but complete example, and the full stack trace.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am in the process of doing so.

Comment: I guess ORM is perfect use case to use this, even if you don't know the field name, you can always enumerate.

Comment: Why is this feature allowed? To a novice like me, it seems like a clear violation of OOP principles.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy: Reflection is quite often a pragmatic solution for otherwise annoying situations. It's definitely worth avoiding where possible, and is often a *bad* solution. I don't know whether I'd go so far as to prohibit it entirely, but I'd always at least be nervous.

Comment: Note for posterity: JPMS modules add more encapsulation regarding reflection; now the package must be `opens` to at least the caller module (if using modules).

Comment: Should we make the field not accessible afterwards?

Comment: @lubumbax: That would very much depend on the use case, I suspect.

Answer (score 56):

Yes.

```
  Field f = Test.class.getDeclaredField("str");
  f.setAccessible(true);//Very important, this allows the setting to work.
  String value = (String) f.get(object);
```

Then you use the field object to get the value on an instance of the class.

Note that get method is often confusing for people. You have the field, but you don't have an instance of the object. You have to pass that to the `get` method

Comment: what's `object` ??

Comment: @Gevorg it is a reference variable pointing to an instance of the class with the private field.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

You need to use the getDeclaredField method (instead of the getField method), with the name of your private field:

```
Field privateField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("str");
```

Additionally, you need to set this Field to be accessible, if you want to access a private field:

```
privateField.setAccessible(true);
```

Once that's done, you can use the get method on the Field instance, to access the value of the str field.