# Accessing Java object fields in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, reflection, undocumented-behavior

I am using a .jar java library for image analysis.  I want to access certain data within an object but there are no public get/set methods provided; using the `fieldnames(object, '-full')` method returns an empty cell array so I assume all the fields are private.

However, when I look at the object in the Matlab variable viewer the data fields I want are visible (I'm presuming the variable viewer shows all the object fields and properties, though on this I am also unsure).

Is there any way of accessing these fields programmatically in Matlab?  I have seen some posts about using reflection but am not clear how/if this works in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: In response to a comment that has now been deleted:  `methodsview` lists the public methods the class exposes.  I want to access data for which the original developer did not provide any public get/set methods.  There may have been good reason to keep the variable private but for my needs I want to extract it for analysis.       What I don't understand is how the Matlab viewer (and tooltip!) can 'see' the data within the class but I cannot access it in my program.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of using Java reflection to access a private field in a class (borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555680/97160))

Take the following Java class (dont forget to make it accessible to MATLAB using `javaaddpath`):

#### Test.java

```
class Test
{
   private String str;
   public Test() {}
   public void setStr(String value) { str = value; }
}
```

First lets instantiate the class:

```
>> t = Test()
t =
Test@62748e
>> t.setStr('foo')
>> t.str
No appropriate method, property, or field str for class Test.
```

Obviously trying to access the private field throws an error. Here is how we can use reflection:

```
>> f = t.getClass().getDeclaredField('str')
f =
private java.lang.String Test.str
>> f.setAccessible(true)
>> f.get(t)
ans =
foo
```