# java data source property

Tags: java, events, vaadin

I have event in Java and I need help how to get value of field (for example of `columnFootersVisible`).

More info - Event is Vaadin Property.ValueChangeEvent

- Event->

  - source->

    - columnFootersVisible   -   false

Here screenshot of event:
[image]

I know I can get source object, but is it possible to get all event data visible in debbuger?

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't the debugger already show you everything?

Comment: Type casting the source object to a particular field object gives more properties.

Comment: So how I could do this for example i posted columnFootersVisible is boolean

Answer (score 0):

IDE have shown you the values of protected (`source`, yellow mark) and private (`columnFootersVisible`, red mark) fields of objects (event and table). While it's possible to access private fields in Java through reflection, the normal way is to use public API.

Both event's `source` and Table's `columnFootersVisible` fields have proper public accessors: [getSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) and [isFooterVisible](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#isFooterVisible%28%29), correspondingly. So, you can use these methods:

```
if(event.getSource() instanceOf Table) {
    Table table = (Table) event.getSource();
    boolean isFooterVisible = table.isFooterVisible();
}
```

If, for some obscure reason, you still want to access private fields directly, then you might want to take a look on this question:

[Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555658/is-it-possible-in-java-to-access-private-fields-via-reflection)