# How is @Autowired implemented in Spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I would really like to have even a basic understanding of how is @autowired
implemented in Spring.
Reflection should be somehow implied in its implementation, but I cannot figure out how.
Can you help ?

Comment: How do you define _basic understanding_? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: High level, not that much into details I mean...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Autowiring through `@Autowired` is performed by a `BeanPostProcessor` implementation, specifically [`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html).

This `BeanPostProcessor` processes every bean, will scan its class (and superclasses) for any `@Autowired` annotations, and, depending on what is annotation (a constructor, field, or method), it will take appropriate action.

For constructors

> Only one constructor (at max) of any given bean class may carry this
>   annotation with the 'required' parameter set to true, indicating the
>   constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean. If multiple
>   non-required constructors carry the annotation, they will be
>   considered as candidates for autowiring. The constructor with the
>   greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching
>   beans in the Spring container will be chosen. If none of the
>   candidates can be satisfied, then a default constructor (if present)
>   will be used. An annotated constructor does not have to be public.

For fields

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any
>   config methods are invoked. Such a config field does not have to be
>   public.

For methods

> Config methods may have an arbitrary name and any number of arguments;
>   each of those arguments will be autowired with a matching bean in the
>   Spring container. Bean property setter methods are effectively just a
>   special case of such a general config method. Config methods do not
>   have to be public.

All of this is done through reflection.

Further reading:

- [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)
- [Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555658/is-it-possible-in-java-to-access-private-fields-via-reflection)

Comment: For fields I'm having hard time understanding how to achieve injection using reflection, can you help ?

Comment: @GionJh What don't you understand?

Comment: maybe It's beacause I don't really know that much about reflection, but how can you inject a value to  private field through reflection, how is that possible ?

Comment: @GionJh See related links in my answer.