# Javascript - Create object without reference

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have problem with create Object instance without reference.

I researched and found many people suggest using `jQuery.extend` to create object without reference.

Refer:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704)

But it not success in my case.

Here is my code
***[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jehucimago/edit?js,console)***

```js
var MyModel = (function() {
  MyModel = function() {};

  var myModelObj = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: {
      sub1: null,
      sub2: null
    }
  };

  MyModel.prototype = {
    getProp1: function() {
      return myModelObj.prop1;
    },
    getSub1: function() {
      return myModelObj.prop2.sub1;
    },
    getSub2: function() {
      return myModelObj.prop2.sub2;
    },
    setProp1: function(val) {
      myModelObj.prop1 = val;
    },
    setSub1: function(val) {
      myModelObj.prop2.sub1 = val;
    },
    setSub2: function(val) {
      myModelObj.prop2.sub2 = val;
    },
    getObj: function() {
      return $.extend({}, myModelObj);
    },
    setObj: function(json_obj) {
      myModelObj.prop1 = json_obj.prop1;
      myModelObj.prop2.sub1 = json_obj.prop2.sub1;
      myModelObj.prop2.sub2 = json_obj.prop2.sub2;
    },
    setParam: function(prop1, sub1, sub2) {
      myModelObj.prop1 = prop1;
      myModelObj.prop2.sub1 = sub1;
      myModelObj.prop2.sub2 = sub2;
    }
  };
  return MyModel;
}());

var model1 = new MyModel();
model1.setParam('prop1', 'sub1', 'sub2');
var model2 = new MyModel();
model2.setParam('clone-prop1', 'clone-sub1', 'clone-sub2');
console.log("object 1");
console.log(model1.getObj());
console.log("object 2");
console.log(model2.getObj());
```

My expected result is

```
model1 = {
   prop1: 'prop1',
   prop2: {
      sub1: 'sub1',
      sub2: 'sub2'
   }
}

model2 = {
   prop1: 'clone-prop1',
   prop2: {
      sub1: 'clone-sub1',
      sub2: 'clone-sub2'
   }
}
```

But actually, `model1` and `model2` have same data of `model2`.

Can someone point me out where i made mistake?

=== ***Update*** ===

@arcyqwerty's solution help me solved create object without reference.

```js
var MyModel = function() {
  this.prop1 = null;
  this.prop2 = {
    sub1: null,
    sub2: null
  };
};

MyModel.prototype = {
  getProp1: function() {
    return this.prop1;
  },
  getSub1: function() {
    return this.prop2.sub1;
  },
  getSub2: function() {
    return this.prop2.sub2;
  },
  setProp1: function(val) {
    this.prop1 = val;
  },
  setSub1: function(val) {
    this.prop2.sub1 = val;
  },
  setSub2: function(val) {
    this.prop2.sub2 = val;
  },
  getObj: function() {
    return $.extend({}, this);
  },
  setObj: function(json_obj) {
    this.prop1 = json_obj.prop1;
    this.prop2.sub1 = json_obj.prop2.sub1;
    this.prop2.sub2 = json_obj.prop2.sub2;
  },
  setParam: function(prop1, sub1, sub2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2.sub1 = sub1;
    this.prop2.sub2 = sub2;
  }
};

var model1 = new MyModel();
model1.setParam('prop1', 'sub1', 'sub2');
var model2 = new MyModel();
model2.setParam('clone-prop1', 'clone-sub1', 'clone-sub2');
console.log("object 1");
console.log(model1.getObj());
console.log("object 2");
console.log(model2.getObj());
```

But I also want use `encapsulation` feature in `OOP`. It means, we only get value object, property through `get` function. Is it possible on `Javascript`?
It explain why i have an object inside Model (but it reference on same object)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that the accepted answer you linked to is not an answer to the question. BTW, the way you've wrapped your code in an IIFE does nothing useful, it's just confusing. Oh, your issue is that *model1* and *model2* both reference the same *myModelObj* object held in a closure by your IIFE. jQuery has nothing to do with the issue, nor does cloning the object.

Comment: @RobG: I want use `encapsulation` feature too. Is it possible on Javascript? Please see my updated question

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The thing being encapsulated (i.e. held in a closure) is *myModelObj*, but it seems that that isn't what you want to do. There is a public *MyModel* constructor in either case, so just use arcyqwerty's answer (which creates the same, single global: *MyModel*).

Comment: @RobG: I mean is it possible to keep it encapsulated & not refer to one object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var MyModel = function() {
  this.prop1 = null;
  this.prop2 = {
    sub1: null,
    sub2: null
  };
};

MyModel.prototype = {
  getProp1: function() {
    return this.prop1;
  },
  getSub1: function() {
    return this.prop2.sub1;
  },
  getSub2: function() {
    return this.prop2.sub2;
  },
  setProp1: function(val) {
    this.prop1 = val;
  },
  setSub1: function(val) {
    this.prop2.sub1 = val;
  },
  setSub2: function(val) {
    this.prop2.sub2 = val;
  },
  getObj: function() {
    return $.extend({}, this);
  },
  setObj: function(json_obj) {
    this.prop1 = json_obj.prop1;
    this.prop2.sub1 = json_obj.prop2.sub1;
    this.prop2.sub2 = json_obj.prop2.sub2;
  },
  setParam: function(prop1, sub1, sub2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2.sub1 = sub1;
    this.prop2.sub2 = sub2;
  }
};

var model1 = new MyModel();
model1.setParam('prop1', 'sub1', 'sub2');
var model2 = new MyModel();
model2.setParam('clone-prop1', 'clone-sub1', 'clone-sub2');
console.log("object 1");
console.log(model1.getObj());
console.log("object 2");
console.log(model2.getObj());
```

The problem with your original constructor is that instances of `MyModel`, although different objects created with the `new` keyword, all share the same `myModelObj` (which is only ever created once).  Using this solution, new fields are created each time you craete a new `MyModel`.

This is similar to having `MyModel = function() { this.myModelObj = {...}; }` and accessing fields using `this.myModelObj.prop` but at that point, `myModelObj` is a bit redundant as you can just set the properties on `this` directly.

Also, using this solution, you can use `model1.prop` directly without having to say `model1.getObj().prop` (although that works too)

--

Note: it's also a little strange for me to see

```
var ClassName = (function() {
  ClassName = function() { ...; };
  ClassName.prototype = { ... };
  return ClassName;
})();
```

Is there a reason you're doing that instead of

```
var ClassName = function() { ... };
ClassName.prototype = { ... };
```

?

I suppose it makes sense in the original code if you didn't want to pollute the namespace with `myModelObj`, but it seems unnecessary otherwise.

--

Edit: encapsulation

If you require an object's properties to be set through getters/setters, you could try something like this:

```
var MyModel = function() {
  var privateObject = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: {
      sub1: null,
      sub2: null
    }
  };
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop1', {
    get: function() { 
      console.log('Getting prop1 through getter');
      return privateObject.prop1;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      console.log('Setting prop1 through setter');
      privateObject.prop1 = value;
    }
  });
};
```

The downside is that you won't be able to share getter/setter functions using the prototype chain, meaning you'll have a lot of function objects hanging around.  For a small number of instances, this is probably fine (performance-wise).  It will also affect inheritance, if your class has subclasses.

If you're on a platform without `defineProperty`, you can also replicate this by keeping the `var privateObject` in the constructor and using `this.getProp1 = function() { return privateObject.prop1; }` in the constructor instead of on the prototype.  The net effect is similar to using `defineProperty`.

--

Edit: or using [getter/setter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

*Note*: the returned object is **not** an `instanceof` `F`.

```
function F() {
  var fields = { prop: null };
  return {
    get prop() {
      console.log("getter");
      return fields.prop;
    },
    set prop(value) {
      console.log("setter");
      fields.prop = value;
    }
  };
}
f = new F
f.prop = 123
f.prop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried your solution and it solved my problem.
But my expectation is user cannot see property directly, like `encapsulation` feature in OOP. If they want get value, they **MUST** get through `get...` function.
That's why i have an object inside Model. Any solution can solve this?

Comment: You can have strong encapsulation, with privacy more strict than in Java or C# (no reflection loopholes), and then have each object contain its own copy of its member functions, or you can have shared methods, in which case the data must be publicly available on the object.  There aren't good options to achieve both.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: of course, the correctness must be highest priority. But I wonder how we protect properties on `Javascript`? Example, use setter method, we can at least check input value before assign to variable.

Comment: Updated with a way to reach your goals, although it breaks prototypical inheritance and results in `fields * 2 * n` `Function` objects for `n` instances (as opposed to `fields * 2` `Function` objects for `n` instances)

Comment: Adding an answer that shows how you can achieve that sort of encapsulation, at the expense of losing the sharing of methods.

Comment: @arcyqwerty: thanks mate! I will try your updated solution. But as you said, the model class become too complex and may affect to performance. I will consider about apply it or keep model simple with good performance :)

Comment: As an additional note, seeing you're coming from Java, some JS code uses appends `_` as part of a naming convention to denote private fields (for example, [Google JS style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml -- it isn't mentioned specifically, but the example code uses this convention).  It's easier to bypass the intended visibility in JS, but even in Java, devs can bypass the visibility intended by the author: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1555680)  The takeaway is that you're expressing "this field is private, don't use it" and it's up to the dev to respect that.

Answer (score 1):

This variant of arcyqwerty's answer demonstrates a much deeper encapsulation of your data.  The trade-off is that each instance gets its own copy of the methods, rather than sharing them at a "class" level:

```
var MyModel = function() {
  var prop1 = null;
  var prop2 = {
    sub1: null,
    sub2: null
  };
  this.getProp1 = function() {
    return prop1;
  };
  this.getSub1 = function() {
    return prop2.sub1;
  };
  this.getSub2 = function() {
    return prop2.sub2;
  };
  this.setProp1 = function(val) {
    prop1 = val;
  };
  this.setSub1 = function(val) {
    prop2.sub1 = val;
  };
  this.setSub2 = function(val) {
    prop2.sub2 = val;
  };
  this.getObj = function() {
    return {
      prop1: prop1,
      prop2: {
        sub1: prop2.sub1,
        sub2: prop2.sub2
      }
    };
  };
  this.setObj = function(json_obj) {
    prop1 = json_obj.prop1;
    prop2.sub1 = json_obj.prop2.sub1;
    prop2.sub2 = json_obj.prop2.sub2;
  };
  this.setParam = function(_prop1, _sub1, _sub2) {
    prop1 = _prop1;
    prop2.sub1 = _sub1;
    prop2.sub2 = _sub2;
  };
};
```

You said,

> But I wonder how we protect properties on `Javascript`?

I think that's the wrong question.  JS is a different language, with different concerns than, say, Java or Ruby.  It is at least as much a functional language as an OO one.  You probably should not try to act as though you're working in Java when you're doing JS, but learn its folkways instead.

Comment: thank you for explain to me! I come to JS with Java background, so they are new to me. And part of my question: `Is it possible on Javascript?` Thanks again :)