# How to mock a cast object

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am new to mock testing and was wondering how I would go about mocking the following with mockito.

```
uDAO = (UserDAO) dao;
```

where dao is defined as

```
protected DAO<T, Long> dao;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Problem is: if something is inherited, than you will have a hard time mocking it. The real solution there is to use dependency injection to ensure that you can provide a matching object to your superclass at some oint.

Comment: how do you get to initialize 'dao' ?

Answer (score 1):

To inject mocks for private and protected fields (which do not have a public setter method) you have to use reflections. Using reflections you can set a mocked object in place of that protected field. Below is a sample of relections code.

```
Field hack = <PUT YOU CLASS NAME>.class.getDeclaredField("dao");
hack.setAccessible(true);
hack.set(<Object of the class where you are injecting the mock>,<the mock object>);
```

To create the mocked object you can use the regular `PowerMockito.mock` or `Mockito.mock` functions.

For more info on reflections have a look at the below links:

[Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555658/is-it-possible-in-java-to-access-private-fields-via-reflection)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Setprivatefieldvalue.htm