# How does Jackson deserializer work by default

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, lombok

I am using `Spring-boot 2.1.6` and i have `DTO`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data // setters, getters, others
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExampleDto {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldsTwo;

}
```

Do i really need that many `Lombok` annotation here? Which will `Jackson` use by default when deserializing over `HTTP` connection (microservices)?
I guess only `NoArgsConstructor` + `setters` would be fine? Or does it use `reflection` and only providing no-arg-constructor is fine?

Is there an option to change behaviour of `Jackson` to use only `AllArgsConstructor` or `builder`?
I saw in logs that my app uses `Jackson` to deserialize stuff.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

My question is different from [Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together) cause it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together)

Comment: @Strelok My question is different from `Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together` cause it works together.

Comment: Maybe you should read the actual linked question because the top voted answer tells you how to use the Lombok builders . You’re hardly trying

Comment: My questions was partly about how `Jackson` works by default I don't see that mentioned there.

Answer (score 9):

Jackson uses default (no argument) constructor to create object and then sets value using setters. so you only need @NoArgsConstructor and @Setter.

Comment: Additional question was: `Is there an option to change behaviour of Jackson to use only AllArgsConstructor or builder`?

Comment: @tryingHard I think this might help you https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/02/01/polymorphism-with-jackson/

Comment: Also if you want to modify any of field you can use your own setters instead of using auto generated setters from lambok

Comment: Does it have to be `public`?

Answer (score 2):

Jackson uses default NoArgsConstructor and Setters.

If you don't provide Setters, jackson will set values using reflection. See - [How does jackson set private properties without setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821319/how-does-jackson-set-private-properties-without-setters)

Answer (score 2):

Although  above answers work to solve the mentioned issue, as an updated answer, according to the [lombok official website](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized), from 1.18.14, `@Jacksonized` was introduced, which automatically configures the generated builder class to be used by Jackson's deserialization. Therefore, your code could be like this:

```
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class ExampleDto {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldsTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Jackson deserialization by default uses the **no-args constructor** and the **setters** of the object. So with Lombok, you'll need a minimum of:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class ExampleDto {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldsTwo;
}
```

(Note if you're ever serializing then you'll need at least a @Getter).

There is an option to override the default deserialization of Jackson to use the Lombok builder. This is covered in top answer to [Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together) (as others have mentioned). I.e.

```
@Builder
@Data
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ExampleDto.ExampleDtoBuilder.class)
public class ExampleDto {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldsTwo;
}

@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "") 
public static class ExampleDtoBuilder {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html) jackson searches for getter- and setter-methods. Also to create an object of the type a default constructor is needed. So basically you need a class that satisfies the [java bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) conventions.

Long story short: You need `@Data` for getter- and setter-methods and `@NoArgsConstructor` for the default constructor to satisfy the bean convention. `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@Builder` should not be needed for jackson.

Comment: Additional question was: `Is there an option to change behaviour of Jackson to use only AllArgsConstructor or builder?`

Comment: I don't think there is such an option, although I'm not quite shure about it. But to use only an `@AllArgsConstructor` jackson would need to know at least the order of elements in the constructor, which should be not possible I think. So it's just an educated guess, but I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using Spring Boot, there should be a Jackson configuration class somewhere annotated with @Configuration. Something like this should enable serialization for your Java bean without the need for any annotation

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
      return mapper;
   }

}
```