# How does spring resolve @autowired field injection is no setter methods are provided?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have recently started with spring and I am facing problem in understanding this small code snipet.

```
@Component
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;
}
@Component
public class B {
}
```

Since there are no setter methods provided and the field 'b' is private, how does spring perform this injection.

Comment: Private doesn't mean much once you delve into the [murky world of reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555680/3195526).